# Mule 3: How to get the HTTP headers from a MuleMessage

Tags: java, mule

Given a `MuleMessage` object that was created from an HTTP request, how do you get the HTTP headers of the request?  I'm using Mule 3.2.1.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTTP headers are stored as inbound-scoped properties.  Their property names are prefixed with `http.`.  For example:

```
MuleMessage message = ...
String contentType = (String)message.getInboundProperty("http.Content-Type");
```

But there are other HTTP-related properties inside of the "http." property namespace as well, such as "http.status" for the status code and "http.request" for the request URL.  So, while it's possible to retrieve *individual* headers, there's no reliable, automated way of getting a *list* of all HTTP headers.

This issue is [slated to be fixed in Mule 3.3](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULECDEV/HTTP+properties+usability+improvement).  Mule 3.3 will organize HTTP-related properties better.  For example, all headers will be stored in a property named "http.headers", and all query string parameters will be parsed and stored in "http.query.params".

Answer (score 5):

All the HTTP headers are in the inbound-scoped properties of the `MuleMessage`.

Comment: Can't such a `MuleMessage`  have other inbound-scoped properties which are *not* HTTP headers?  If so, how do I know which ones are the HTTP headers?  Thanks.

Comment: You will have Mule specific headers as well, which are prefixed with `MULE_`, and also transport specific headers, which are prefixed with `http.`. You should be able to sort the wheat from the chaff.

Comment: Thanks David.  According to this page, http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULECDEV/HTTP+properties+usability+improvement, it doesn't look like there's any reliable way of getting a list of all the HTTP headers in Mule 3.2.1.  However, in version 3.3 (see JIRA ticket), all HTTP properties will be organized better, so that they're not all jumbled into "http.".  For example, all headers will be organized in a Map inside the "http.headers" property.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check by putting log message

```
<logger message="=============test= #[message.inboundProperties]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Let me  know if that works for you.

Thanks